# Creating equivalent expressions by changing the domains and predicates

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm having trouble finding a third way to make a logical expression.

> Translate this statement into a logical expression in 3 different ways by varying the domain and by using predicates with one and with two variables.
>
> Someone in your school has visited Mexico

I've made 2 translations:

Domain = person in your school
C(x) = x has visited Mexico
$$∃xC(x)$$

Domain = people in the world
S(x) = x in your school
$$∃x(S(x)\land C(x))$$

Yet I don't know what to change to create a third translation.

Answer (score 1):

Domain = all objects
$S(x) := x$ is a person in your school
$M(x) := x$ is Mexico
$V(x,y) := x$ has visited $y$

$$∃x∃y\;\big( S(x) ∧ M(y) ∧ V(x,y) \big)$$